How to load application.js build by webpack using sprockets
I'm moving an elderly application from rails 5.x to 7.2. Most things are working except loading application.js.
After following the migration guide and moved to jsbundling-rails, I have two application.js files
app/assets/javascripts/application js
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the     bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require_tree .

app/javascript/application.js
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import jQuery from "jquery";
import "bootstrap";

The application.js is used by yarn properly but the results are not included in the served html.
How can I tell sprockets to use the js output generated by webpack / jsbundling-rails?

sprockets can load whatever is compiled into app/assets/builds/. can't have two application.js assets, you should rename app/assets/javascripts/application.js if you still need it, otherwise, delete it.

I've merged both to the app/assets/javascripts/application.js and configured webpack to build that file. But that doesn't solve the problem that the generated output is not added to html.
How can sprockets know, where to find the output of yarn build command?

yarn build outputs app/assets/builds/application.js and sprockets will load it with <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

With the comments of Alex I was able to find the problem. I've adopted webpack.config.js from a tutorial which placed the output in the wrong folder.
webpack.config.js - not working
output: {
  filename: "[name].js",
  chunkFilename: "[name]-[contenthash].digested.js",
  sourceMapFilename: "[file]-[fullhash].map",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app/assets/builds'),
  hashFunction: "sha256",
  hashDigestLength: 64,
},

webpack.config.js - working
output: {
  filename: "[name].js",
  sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",
  chunkFormat: "module",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/assets/builds"),
},

Also the application.js must resist in "./app/javascript/application.js" otherwise sprockets will catch the source and the output file and fails loading the assets.
